# Visual Studio 2017, I don't want to submit some .cs file changes in Git

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2017

I don't want to submit just some .cs file changes in Visual Studio 2017, Git. I am waiting to hear from the person who made the request to continue working on some files. According to the news, I will continue coding or undo the changes I have made. But in order not to waste time waiting for that news that I need right now, I started a new job and finished it. I just want to push the .cs file I just finished.

I just want to push the Receptions.cs file to GitHub as seen in the screenshots. I don't want to submit the ReceptionForm.cs file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last screenshot, that's the goal of the `Stage` menu item to be able to add in the staging area (also called 'index') only the changes you want to put in the commit you will create next.

So you can stage or unstage respectly the files you want to commit or not.

Side note: Normally git even allows you to add/stage just some parts of the changes made in a given file but if I remember well this git feature is not supported by this version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, as you said, by saying Stage, I have reserved only that .cs file for sending. Yes, many features are missing as this version of VS is outdated. Thank you for your support. :) https://imgur.com/gallery/Gu4tWo8